# How to build the latest JBoss AS

Tags: build, jboss, jboss7.x, build-process

Redhat have decided to stop providing downloadable, ready-built binaries of JBoss. At the time of writing the latest downloadable version is an Alpha build EAP 6.1.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4).

This doesn't mean that you now need to have a paid-for licence to run the later versions. It only means that you are now expected to download the source and build them yourself. ***(Edit: To clarify a little, you do need to pay for the later versions of EAP 6 (only Alpha releases are free) but you can get later versions of the code which the EAP Alpha release was based on by going to later versions of AS than the Alpha was based on. When you start the downloaded version of 6.1.0.Alpha it reports "6.1.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.2.0.Alpha1-redhat-4)" when it starts. To get many bug fixes you can download the 7.2.0.Final release).***

Leaving aside the massive confusion brought about by the fact that the EAP and AS versions now are on 6 and 7 respectively, the decision to stop providing those downloads has caused a lot of headaches.

So, how do you build your own binaries of JBoss now?

Comment: For those interested, a lot of explanations about JBoss AS 7 / EAP 6 will be found in this FAQ : http://jbossas.jboss.org/faq

Answer (score 4):

This uses a build of AS 7.2.0.Final (there's a tricky tag for this one - see below) as the example since, at the time of writing, that's the latest JBoss AS build.

It takes about 20 mins on a top spec Macbook Pro (again at the time of writing). Most of that time is spent running thousands of tests. The resulting binaries are exactly what used to be available for download from the Redhat site. Just because you built them locally doesn't make them somehow "less stable" than the binaries you used to be able to download. There's no difference between you building them and someone at Redhat building them and then uploading them. (I know *you* know that but not everyone does.)

The tags should be available here (which is a good way to check what the latest version actually is!): https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tags

The example is obviously for a *nix machine but should apply with almost no changes to a Windows machine.

You will need git and Maven installed (but if you're running JBoss you probably already have!).

***Note: Do not have a JBoss instance running when building this! The tests detect a running instance and fail, to avoid confusion with which JBoss is being tested.***

```
cd anyDirectoryWhereYoupPeferBuildsToBe
git clone https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly.git
cd wildfly
git checkout 7.2.0.Final-testsuite-fix
mvn clean install -Drelease=true
```

Once it is built, just smoke test the sever:

```
cd build/target/jboss-as-7.2.0.Final/bin/
./standalone.sh
```

You should now find the release version as a zip file in the directory dist/target

Comment: If you don't need to run tests, you could add -DskipTests -T1C that will parallelize build to as many cores as you have in your machine. On recent hardware with SSD this should take about 2 minutes.